# ConTeXt: Simplifying mathmatrix notation with separatedlist

Tags: matrices, context

I find myself using a lot of matrices, and I would like to save myself some typing by using the `separatedlist` environment from the `database` module, but I keep getting errors.

The following produces a "Missing number, treated as zero" error:

```
\usemodule[database]

\defineseparatedlist
  [Test]
  [before={\startmathmatrix},
   after={\stopmathmatrix},
   first=,
   last={\NR},
   left={\NC},
   right=,
   separator={;}]

\starttext

\startformula
\startTest
  x_{1,1}; x_{1,2}; x_{1,3}
  1; 2; 3
\stopTest
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

But changing `mathmatrix` to `align` seems to work with no issues:

```
\usemodule[database]

\defineseparatedlist
  [Test]
  [before={\startalign[n=3]},
   after={\stopalign},
   first=,
   last={\NR},
   left={\NC},
   right=,
   separator={;}]

\starttext

\startformula
\startTest
  x_{1,1}; x_{1,2}; x_{1,3}
  1; 2; 3
\stopTest
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to define a new command for easily typesetting matrices. ConTeXt already has a mechanism which uses the MATLAB notation for matrices. To use it, simply specify `simplecommand=NAME`, and then the macro `\NAME{...}` can be used to typeset matrices. For example

```
\definemathmatrix [bmatrix][matrix:brackets][simplecommand=MATRIX]

\starttext
\startformula
  \MATRIX{1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9} 
  \MATRIX{2;3;4}
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

gives

[image]